# Wordpress, ошибка - mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

Посмотреть все похожие вопросы, но не нашел ответа, да и код отличается. Собственно, пытаюсь в WP при отправке формы отправить письмо, создать пользователя, от его имени пост и комментарий к посту. Код следующий:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['submitted'])) {

$contact_name = $_GET['contact_name'];
$contact_name = htmlspecialchars($contact_name);
$contact_name = trim($contact_name);
$contact_phone = $_GET['contact_phone'];
$contact_phone = htmlspecialchars($contact_phone);
$contact_phone = trim($contact_phone);
$contact_email = $_GET['contact_email'];
$contact_email = htmlspecialchars($contact_email);
$contact_email = trim($contact_email);
$text = $_GET['text'];
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
$text = trim($text);

mail("ivan.mv46@gmail.com", "Новое сообщение", "Имя:".$contact_name."\nEmail: ".$contact_email."\nНомер телефона: ".$contact_phone."\nСообщение:".$text."");

$user_id = wp_create_user( $contact_name, 'password', $contact_email );

$post_meta = array(
    'post_author'   => $user_id,
    'post_title'    => $contact_name,
    'post_content'  => 'Нет',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'clients'
    );

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_meta ); 
add_post_meta($post_id, 'object_types', 'Не добавлено', true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'area', 'Не добавлено', true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'adress', 'Не добавлено', true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'client_phone', $contact_phone, true);

$data = array(
    'comment_post_ID'      => $post_id,
    'comment_author'       => $user_id,
    'comment_content'      => $text,
    'comment_date'         => date('d-m-Y'),
    'comment_approved'     => 1,
    );

wp_insert_comment( $data );

echo "Спасибо, ваше сообщение отправлено. Скоро мы свяжемся с вами.";
wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
exit;
} ?>
<form class="single_contact_form flex_cc main_bg">
<input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="contact_name" required>
<input type="tel" placeholder="Номер телефона" name="contact_phone" required pattern="(\+?\d[- .]*){7,13}" title="Международный, государственный или местный телефонный номер">
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="contact_email" required>
<textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="6"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Код работает, письмо приходит и все остальное тоже выполняется. Но после на странице я вижу следующее:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in .../wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1171
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in .../wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1171
Спасибо, ваше сообщение отправлено. Скоро мы свяжемся с вами.
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at .../header.php:1) in /wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1195
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вижу тут две ошибки.

`Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string()` возникает из-за того, что в качестве `$user_id` в `wp_insert_comment()` передается объект `WP_Error`, который возвращает `wp_create_user()` в том случае, когда пользователь с таким email уже существует.

`Warning: Cannot modify header information` - из-за того, что нельзя делать никакой вывод на страницу до `wp_redirect()`. Эта функция использует php-функцию header, почитайте о ней [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php).

Даже если вы уберете echo из своего кода, вторая ошибка все равно будет возникать из-за вывода на страницу первого сообщения об ошибке.

UPDATE

Чтобы не возникала первая ошибка, проверяйте, есть ли уже такой пользователь перед созданием:

```
$user = get_user_by('email', $contact_email);
if ( ! $user ) {
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $contact_name, 'password', $contact_email );
} else {
    $user_id = $user->ID;
}
```

Comment: То есть, ничего страшного с первой ошибкой, все понятно. Но, в таком случае, если пользователь уже есть, можете подсказать, как подставить его id в $user_id? А с редиректом я разобрался, просто хотел почистить url от get-запроса, сделал через javascript

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо! Исользуя ваш ответ, еще улучшил свой код, добавив проверку, существует ли уже пост от пользователя, и если он есть, добавляет пост, иначе добавляет коммент к уже существующему. Все работает, премного благодарен.

Comment: вот код проверки, если не трудно - проверьте, правильно ли я сделал https://codepen.io/malginovdesign/pen/XRLmZY